# Twilio React Native Video call freeze issue

Tags: react-native, twilio, videochat

I have been using the following Twilio library to implement video calling in my  React Native app.

**react-native-twilio-video-webrtc**

the video call works perfectly on the first call. However, on the second attempt, the video is frozen but the audio works fine.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me point out the right direction.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sharing the same video and audio tracks between calls? Can you share your code at all?